# Relativistic formula for wavelength given a particle with mass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

The formula for the wavelength of potential difference $V$ required to give a particle of mass $m$ and charge $q$ is $\lambda =\frac{h}{\sqrt{2mqV}}$ but what will the formula be for relativistic speeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For low speed you could use Newton's relation
between kinetic energy $E_k$ and momentum $p$:
$$E_k=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$

But for high speed this is no longer valid.
You need to use the [relativistic energy-momentum relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation) instead:
$$(mc^2+E_k)^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$$

Solving for momentum $p$ you get
$$p=\sqrt{2mE_k+\left(\frac{E_k}{c}\right)^2}.$$

Applying energy conservation ($E_k=qV$) and
de Broglie's relation ($\lambda=h/p$) here you finally get
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{\sqrt{2mqV+\left(\frac{qV}{c}\right)^2}}.$$